# Is this multivariable calculus?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

The following is a question from Calculus made easy by Silvanus P. Thompson

> The volume of a right circular cylinder of radius $r$ and height $h$ is given by the formula $V=πr^2h$. Find the rate of variation of volume with the radius when $r = 5.5 \text{in}$. and $h = 20 \text{in}$. If $r = h$, find the dimensions of the cylinder so that a change of 1 in. in radius causes a change of 400 cubic inches in the volume.

I understand the solution to the problem apart from the second part when $r=h$. I got the first solution for that when I took h as a constant but there is second answer for the question in which $h$ varies with $r$ shown below:

$$\frac {dV}{dr}=3πr^2$$
 $$=400$$

and then we solve for $r$ which is equal to $h$. My question is isn't this multivariable calculus and is this method correct?

Comment: You have applied the power rule wrongly, $\frac{d}{dr}[\pi r^3]=3\pi r^2$ other than that the method is correct.

Comment: @ Filthyscrub sorry someone suggested an edit to make it look better so they caused the error

Comment: I half expected to see the meme with the butterfly somewhere.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Short answer: No.

Long(ish) answer: This is not multivariable calculus, because multivariable calculus deals with multiple *independent* variables, whereas the problem in question deals with *dependent* variables.

To help illustrate my point, here is an example.

It would be multivariable calculus to find the maximum values of the function $$f(x,y)=\frac{\sin(x+y)}{x^2+y^2+1}$$
for *all* real numbers $x$ and $y$.

By contrast, it would be a single-variable calculus problem to find the maximum values of $$\frac{\sin(x+y)}{x^2+y^2+1}=c,$$
where $c$ is a *constant*. This is because, by setting the function $f$ equal to a constant, you are *implicitly* defining $y$ in terms of $x$, and thus there is only one independent variable to work with, namely $x$.

Let me know if this helps. :)

Comment: so in multivariable calculus each variable varies independently with the function f(x,y)?

Comment: @sniperking Exactly!

Comment: But doesn't varying one affect the other? How can they vary independently?

Comment: @sniperking No. Varying one does not effect the value of the other. Simply, just plug in any two real numbers $x$ and $y$, and $f(x,y)$ is defined to be able to evaluate them.

Comment: thanks i understand now. Also is the solution in the book correct?

Comment: @sniperking If the varaibles were dependent, the graph of the function would lie in the xy-plane. However, the graph of $f(x,y)$, since it takes two inputs, is the set of points $(x,y,z)$ in $3$d space, where $z=f(x,y)$

Comment: @sniperking other than your mistake with the power rule, your solution is correct

Comment: Nice answer, beautiful example!$(+1)$

Comment: @soheil I'm so glad you enjoyed it :)